# Variable mass of orbiting body

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, variable-mass-systems

Considering an object orbiting earth at radius $R$ and speed $v$, at one moment in time the mass of the object starts to decrease, what will happen to the object in terms of speed and orbit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed and orbit remain unchanged if we can neglect non-gravitational forces, such as the pressure of the solar wind.

Suppose the mass of the object goes from $m_1$ to $m_2 = \alpha m_1$. Then all the gravitational forces on it change from $\vec{F_1}$ to $\vec{F_2} = \alpha \vec{F_1}$, but the new accelerations

$$
\vec{a_2} = \frac{\vec{F_2}}{m_2} = \frac{\alpha \vec{F_1}}{\alpha m_1} = \frac{\vec{F_1}}{m_1} = \vec{a_1}
$$

are the same as the ones before the change of the mass. Consequently, trajectory of the object is unchanged.